# Google Dashboard multiple controls for one table only showing last control

Tags: google-visualization

Problem:  I have three controls in a dashboard connected to one table, but only the last control shows up in my UI.  Please run the code below and notice that the prefServFilter is the only one showing up.

I followed this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) information.  I put my controls in a array to bind 'many-to-one'. Here's the little snippet pertaining to my situation:

> // Many-to-one binding where 'ageSelector' and 'salarySelector' concurrently
>   // participate in selecting which data 'ageVsSalaryScatterPlot' visualizes.
>
> dashboard.bind([agePicker,salaryPicker], ageVsSalaryScatterPlot);

I can't seem to figure why this is happening, does anyone see a solution? What am I missing?  I also checked Google's issue tracker and didn't find anything regarding this.

```js
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table', 'controls']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initializeClient);
    
            function initializeClient() {
              var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H');
              var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VhDR4B9EjkrITkXRCcrSiJXXPD-q-ud2CQ03XE51o1o/edit?usp=sharing&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
              query.send(drawClientDashboard);
            }
    
            function drawClientDashboard(response) {
              var data = response.getDataTable(); 
    
              // create a dashboard
              var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard( document.getElementById('client-dashboard') );
    
              // categoryFilter for name
               var nameFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                 'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                 'containerId': 'client-filter',
                 'options': {
                   'filterColumnIndex': 0,
                   'ui.labelStacking':'vertical'
                 }
               });
    
              // categoryFilter for type of business
               var bizTypeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                 'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                 'containerId': 'client-filter',
                 'options': {
                   'filterColumnIndex': 1,
                   'ui.labelStacking':'vertical'
                 }
               });
    
               // stringFilter for associated cofc
                var prefServFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                  'controlType': 'StringFilter',
                  'containerId': 'client-filter',
                  'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': 6,
                    'ui.labelStacking':'vertical'
                  }
                });
    
    
               var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                 'chartType': 'Table',
                 'containerId': 'client-table',
                 'options': {
                   'width': '100%',
                   'height': '500px'
                 }
               });
    
               // bind my 3 controls to table
               dashboard.bind([nameFilter, bizTypeFilter, prefServFilter], table);

               dashboard.draw(data);
    
    
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    
    <body>
        <div id="client-dashboard">
         <div id="client-filter"></div>
         <div id="client-table"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: each control needs its own container `<div>` with a unique id -- currently, all have the same --> `'containerId': 'client-filter'` -- last one to draw wins...

Comment: Yes! of Course!  seems so obvious now.  Thank you!